# Background image not showing up in heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image, heroku, sass

I'm having issues with the background image for my heroku site, locally using

```
background-image: url('background_stripe.png');
```

works but when deployed the file is broken

[image: Website]

I've tried using

```
background-image: image-url('background_stripe.png');
background-image: url(image-url('background_stripe.png'));
background-image: url(image_url('background_stripe.png'));
```

none of which worked locally or on heroku.

Using bash I've found out heroku has named the image file background_stripe.png but it has no hash and its a broken image

Comment: Is the `background_stript.png` image in the same folder as the HTML & CSS page? `background-image: url('background_stripe.png');` is the correct way of defining it - examples can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: what is the absolute path of that image ?

Comment: Yes it was defined as background-image: url('img'); already and it was not working, @Paritosh Piplewar app/assets/images/background_stripe.png

Comment: Is `iamge-url` a typo in your code or just in your question?  Also, what does the compiled CSS look like?

Comment: @cimmanon good catch just a typo in the question :P

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In your production.rb add the following line

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

or you can try to precompile the assets locally using

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: This worked thanks! Specifically changing the values to true.

Comment: Changing the production.rb works.  Thanks, @deep.  It looks like `config.serve_static_assets` will be deprecated. `config.serve_static_files` should be used in its place.

Answer (score 6):

When your assets get compiled for production, they get a 'digest' added to the end of them for versioning purposes. You should use `asset_path('background_stripe.png')` if you're defining the class in your views or `image-url('background_stripe.png')` if you're defining them in your SCSS files as referenced in [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass).

Comment: Yes i used image-url aswell since its in app/assets/images but it didn't seem to work

Comment: worked for me using image_url, with an underscore instead of a dash.